# Method for proving a set is the sum of two others

Tags: linear-algebra

If I want to prove a set is the sum of two others is it generally always using the same method? If I want to prove that a set is a sum of two others should I always show that a generic element in the set can be written as a sum of two elements in the other sets?

For instance if I want to show if
$U=\{(x,x,y,y) \in \mathbb{F}^{4}:x,y \in\mathbb{F}\}$,$W=\{(x,x,x,y) \in \mathbb{F}^{4}:x,y \in\mathbb{F}\}$,$S=\{(x,x,y,z) \in \mathbb{F}^{4}:x,y,z \in\mathbb{F}\}$

That $S=U+W$

Method:

let $s=(x,x,y,z)\in S$

Then $u=(a,a,b,b)\in U$ and $w=(c,c,c,d) \in W$

Then $u+w=(a+c,a+c,b+c,b+d) \in U+W$

Letting $x=a+c,y=b+c,z=b+d$

Thus $s=u+w \in U+W$ thus $S=U+W$

Comment: You have successfully proved that $U+W\subseteq S$.

Answer (score 1):

Have you learned about the [Minkowski sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_addition) in linear algebra? 
Let's say they are vector (sub)spaces, i.e.
$$\forall x,y\in U(W),\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb F:\alpha x+\beta y\in U(W)$$
which means they are closed on all linear combinations of all the elements they consist of.
Next problem:
What is $S$? 
$$\dim S=?$$

Generally speaking, sum (union) of $\text{vector spaces}$ isn't necessarily a vector space.
You have to prove:
$$U+W=[U\cup W]=[\{S\}]$$
or, what @almagest has already said:
$$[U\cup W]\subseteq [\{S\}]\;\land\;[\{S\}]\subseteq [U\cup W]$$
$$(U+W)\leq S\;\land\;S\leq (U+W)$$
I used braces here to highlight the $\text{linear span of a vector set}$, because, later on, you'll be introduced to quotient space and use similar, only similar notation for equivalence classes in a quotient space.

$U+W$ can mean you added all the terms mutually $\text{(vector addition)}$, but it is definitely not equal to $S$ until you explicitly prove:
$$\dim S=\dim U+\dim W -\dim (U\cap W)$$
Your first step:
$$U\subseteq S\;\&\;W\subseteq S$$
$$U\leq S\;\&\; W\leq S$$
(:

(:

Answer (score 0):

You have the idea but it is not totally correct. What you want to prove in here is that $S=U+W$, which is a set equality, and usually to prove this you have to prove that $S \subseteq U+W$ and $U+W \subseteq S$. In this case you have to take an arbitrary vector of $S$ and prove that it is a sum of a vector from $U$ and one from $W$, which proves the first contention, and then take an arbitrary vector from $U+W$ and prove that it belongs to $S$, which proves the other contention.